# Why can't I inject a dependancy into a ContentPage?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, ioc-container, tinyioc

Please see the code below:

```
public partial class MyContentPage : ContentPage
    {

        public CreditCardView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

It works as expected.  Now say I want to inject a dependancy:

```
public partial class MyContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly IMyService _myService;

        public CreditCardView(IMyService myService)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _myService=myService;
        }
}
```

With the second excerpt of code I see a compilation error: "The given key was not present in the dictionary".  What is the problem? I have registered the dependancy.

Comment: XAML pages require a default constructor

Comment: @Jason, thanks.  Is it not possible to use a parameterized constructor (with a default constructor)?

Comment: in C# the default constructor is parameterless.  It would probably make more sense to inject your service into your VM, not directly into the page.  That would avoid this problem

Comment: I agreee with Jason. If for some reason you still want to access your service within your view you might want to use Xamarin.Forms [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction). The cleaner approach would be to use MVVM and inject the service into your ViewModel